# What are the recommended remedies for childless couples who are eager?

Tags: sin, children, prayaschitta

I am very sure and believe that the previous birth sins will follow a person in the next birth. Hence, due to sins committed in the previous births, some of the couples don't have children in this birth.

I need to know what they will have to do as a remedy/parigaram as per Hinduism? Its also called like yaagam and homam.

My question- What are the recommended remedies for childless couples who are eager?

P.S: I am not looking for "please visit the doctor" kind of advice. So, please excuse.

Comment: He is not asking for vrat any where in the Q.. He is asking about parihara or remedies..that's why prayschitta comes in..@sarva

Comment: @Rickross Remedy means not a Prayaschitta. Prayaschitta means which is done for a sin. The word for that is expiation or atonement. Here, the OP didn't commit any sin and not asking for an expiation of a sin.  Vratas and Pujas are the remedies for which [tag:vrata] is apt.  The name is Sarvabhouma btw.

Comment: Yes here sin is involed..read OP's Q again..he says because of past life sins one suffers in the current life..now what to do as a remedy? so he is clearly asking about sin and atonement measures..he has nowhere specified about the type of the remedies..it can be homa or fast (vrata) or even charity.. @Sarvabhouma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The remedy for the couples who doesn't have child is mentioned in  Chapter 63 - Of [**Varaha Purana**](http://archive.indianscriptures.com/scriptures/puranas-18-puranas-mahapurana/the-varaha-purana/vol-i/chapter-63/topic-1) - **PutraPrapti Vrata.** This vrata is worshiping Lord Vishnu as Shree Krishna.

Here is the entire Vrata with the description of Homa you enquired from varaha Purana.

> Agastya Said -
>
> 1 : O king now listen to the brief account of the Putra-Prapti Vrata ,
>   I am going to give you.
>
> 2: This Putra-Prapti Vrata (vow for getting son) is to be performed
>   fasting on the Astami tithi in the dark half of the month of
>   Bhadrapada.
>
> **3: The sankalpa should be made on Saptami day and the worship of vishnu as krishna lying in the Devaki's lap surrounded by the mothers
>   should be conducted on Astami.**
>
> 4: On the Astami Day ,early in the morning ,Vishnu should be worshiped
>   with full concentration of mind.
>
> **5: Then Homa should be performed with barley ,black sesamum ghee and curd .Brahmans should be fed and given Dakshina.**
>
> 6: Then the performer of the Vrata may take food ,first Bilva leaves
>   and then with oils and other items.
>
> 7: Doing in this way the KrishnaPaksha Astami every month ,an
>   issueless person begets children.
>
> 8-10 : It is known that in the ancient times the valiant king surasena
>   who was issueless ,performed penance in the Himalayas. And Lord
>   himself told him about this vrata and accordingly he performed it and
>   got a son named Vasudeva by name who later on performed many
>   sacrifices and the saintly king surasena gained salvation.
>
> 11 :This o king I have told you about Krishnasami (in this vrata) ,at
>   the end of the year ,a pair of cows should be gifted to Brahmin .
>
> 12. Such is the Putravrata narrated to you. By performing it one get freed from all sins.
>
>     ---
>
>     [image]
>       [image]

Comment: Note the word Putra referred to both Son and Daughter as this vrata is to be performed issueless couples who want children .